# System.FormatException ZModem Protocol

Tags: c#, string

Hola estoy trabajando con el lenguaje de programación C# y con un protocolo de comunicación llamado Zmodem. Yo descargue el archivo .dll para implementar funciones que permitan realizar la comunicación, pero cuando intento realizar mi código una excepción es lanzada y no se a qué se refiere. 
La función ZModemSend necesita la dirección del archivo que será enviado y el tiempo que necesitara esperar mientras la comunicación es establecida, de esta forma yo cree un openFileDialog para buscar el archivo en el ordenador y obtener la dirección completa donde está alojado, la dirección es guardada en una variable tipo String llamada filenameDIR. 
Cuando trato de correr el programa una excepción es lanzada y dice: System.FormatException: 'Format String can be only "G","g","X","x","F","f","D","d".'

Alguien sabe a qué se refiere o que es lo que está pasando. Debido a que el archivo existe, pero no me deja continuar más allá. 
Eh gastado mucho tiempo investigando que es lo que puede estar mal, pero no eh podio encontrar nada. 
Se los agradecería mucho.

[image: Code 1]

[image: Code 2]

[image: Code 3]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using ZModem_Protocol;
using ZmodemTest;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ZmodemTest
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    SerialPort port;
    String filenameDIR;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        ComboBox_PortNames.Items.AddRange(ports);

    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonConect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox_PortNames.Text != null)
        {
            port = new SerialPort(ComboBox_PortNames.Text, 115200, Parity.None);
            LabelState.Text = "Conected";
        }
    }

    private void buttonLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a txt file";

        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //labelDirFile.Text = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory;
            labelNameFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            filenameDIR = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort_Fix.SerialPortFixer.Execute(port.PortName);
        }
        catch (Exception v)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SerialPort fixer exception: " + v.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        ZModem_Protocol.ZModem zmodem = new ZModem_Protocol.ZModem(port);
        FileInfo fileInfo = null;
        if (!File.Exists(@filenameDIR)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Holaaaa");
        }
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(@filenameDIR);

        //if (!File.Exists(filenameDIR))
        //{
        //    throw new Exception("File not found");
        //}
        //FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filenameDIR);
        //Console.WriteLine("rz\r");
        //String test = "test.txt";
        //FileStream file = File.Open(@"test.txt", FileMode.Open);

        try
        {
            zmodem.ZModemSend(filenameDIR, 10);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Dentro de la libreria .dll Se encuentra este metodo ZModemSend, que es el que se utiliza para realizar la comunicación.

```
public bool ZModemSend(string fileName, int timeOutS)
        {
            byte[] numArray;
            FileInfo fileInfo = null;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                throw new Exception("File not found");
            }
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            if (!this.portserie.IsOpen)
            {
                this.portserie.Open();
            }
        Queue<byte> nums = new Queue<byte>();
        ZModem.BuildZRQINITFrame();
        this.SendCommand("rz\r");
        this.SendCommand(ZModem.BuildZRQINITFrame());
        while (this.portserie.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            nums.Enqueue((byte)this.portserie.ReadByte());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Answer to ZRQINIT from device:");
        while (nums.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(nums.Dequeue());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        byte[] numArray1 = null;
        numArray1 = ZModem.BuildZFILEFrame(fileInfo.Name, (int)fileInfo.Length);
        this.SendCommand(numArray1);
        while (this.portserie.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            nums.Enqueue((byte)this.portserie.ReadByte());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Answer to ZFILE from device:");
        while (nums.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(nums.Dequeue());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            numArray1 = ZModem.BuildZDATAFrame(0);
            this.portserie.Write(numArray1, 0, (int)numArray1.Length);
            int num = 0;
            Crc16Ccitt crc16Ccitt = new Crc16Ccitt(Crc16Ccitt.InitialCrcValue.Zeros);
            while (binaryReader.PeekChar() > 0)
            {
                if (num == 256)
                {
                    SerialPort serialPort = this.portserie;
                    byte[] numArray2 = new byte[] { 24, 105 };
                    serialPort.Write(numArray2, 0, 2);
                    crc16Ccitt.AddByteToComputeChecksum(105);
                    byte[] cRC = crc16Ccitt.getCRC();
                    numArray = ZModem.ZDLEEncoding(cRC[1]);
                    this.portserie.Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
                    numArray = ZModem.ZDLEEncoding(cRC[0]);
                    this.portserie.Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
                    num = 0;
                    crc16Ccitt = new Crc16Ccitt(Crc16Ccitt.InitialCrcValue.Zeros);
                }
                byte num1 = binaryReader.ReadByte();
                crc16Ccitt.AddByteToComputeChecksum(num1);
                numArray = ZModem.ZDLEEncoding(num1);
                this.portserie.Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
                num++;
            }
            SerialPort serialPort1 = this.portserie;
            byte[] numArray3 = new byte[] { 24, 104 };
            serialPort1.Write(numArray3, 0, 2);
            crc16Ccitt.AddByteToComputeChecksum(104);
            byte[] cRC1 = crc16Ccitt.getCRC();
            numArray = ZModem.ZDLEEncoding(cRC1[1]);
            this.portserie.Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
            numArray = ZModem.ZDLEEncoding(cRC1[0]);
            this.portserie.Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
            num = 0;
            crc16Ccitt = new Crc16Ccitt(Crc16Ccitt.InitialCrcValue.Zeros);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            while (this.portserie.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                nums.Enqueue((byte)this.portserie.ReadByte());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Answer to ZDATA from device:");
            if (nums.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("transmission Error!");
            }
            while (nums.Count > 0)
            {
                if (nums.Peek() != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(nums.Dequeue());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CRC Error!");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            this.SendCommand(ZModem.BuildZEOFFrame((int)fileStream.Position));
            while (this.portserie.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                nums.Enqueue((byte)this.portserie.ReadByte());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Answer to ZEOF from device:");
            while (nums.Count > 0)
            {
                if (nums.Peek() != 8)
                {
                    Console.Write(nums.Dequeue());
                }
                else
                {
                    nums.Dequeue();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            binaryReader.Close();
        }
        while (this.portserie.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            nums.Enqueue((byte)this.portserie.ReadByte());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Answer to ZFIN from device:");
        while (nums.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(nums.Dequeue());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        this.SendCommand(ZModem.SessionAbortSeq);
        this.portserie.Close();
        return false;
    }
```

Revise y resulta que donde lanza la excepción es en este método a la hora de utilizar .ToString(). Lo que no comprendo es si esta bien colocado los parámetros de la función para que efectivamente retorne un String.

```
    private static string BuildHexFrame(ZModem.HeaderType type, int arg0, 
int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            string[] hexCommonHeader = new string[] { 
ZModem.HexCommonHeader, type.ToString("x2"), arg0.ToString("x2"), 
arg1.ToString("x2"), arg2.ToString("x2"), arg3.ToString("x2") };
        string str = string.Concat(hexCommonHeader);
        int num = ZModem.ComputeHeaderCRC((int)type, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        str = string.Concat(str, num.ToString("x4"));
        return string.Concat(str, ZModem.EndOfCommand);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, en lugar de colocar screenshots ayudara mucho si colocas el código directamente, así recibirás mas atención.

Comment: Listo , agregue el código que estoy utilizando.

Comment: La pregunta debe estar solo en español. Este sitio es en español.

Comment: Tal vez si nos dices que libreria es y de donde la sacaste, podamos ayudarte a encontrar el error, pero definitivamente ese string que le estas pasando esta mal.

Comment: La libreria la encontre en esta pagina : https://sourceforge.net/projects/zmodem4dotnet/ es un .dll 
Simplemente se pasa el String del nombre de dirección del archivo

Comment: Me decis hasta que mensaje dentro de la dll llega la consola? porque asi va a ser un poco dificil ayudarte. al parecer esa libreria no esta bien, no parece que tu codigo este mal

Comment: Realice una modificación de la librería para comprobar donde era que lanzaba la excepción. Sin embargo parece ser que cuando revisa si el archivo existe pasa, no tiene problemas y posterior ah eso salta la excepción. 
También intente colocar las funciones y declaraciones del método dentro de mi programa y revisar donde se rompe , pero al parecer esta bien. 
Se supone que recibe un String, pero no entiendo por que habla de formato, si no estoy pasando un numero convertido a String.

Comment: Revise el código y encontré donde lanza la excepción , ya subí la actualización con el método donde sucede.